# connect bitbucket pipeline to cpanel with API keys

Tags: cpanel, ssh-keys, bitbucket-pipelines

How do I use SSH Keys (created from cPanel) to connect to the server? And eventually pull a fresh copy and run composer updates and database migrations (a Symfony script)

I get permission denied errors so my `ssh example.net.au ls -l /staging.example.net.au` is reaching the server, I'm just unsure how to use keys made from cPanel to make an authentication.

**bitbucket-pipelines.yml**

```
# This is an example Starter pipeline configuration
# Use a skeleton to build, test and deploy using manual and parallel steps
# -----
# You can specify a custom docker image from Docker Hub as your build environment.
image: atlassian/default-image:2

pipelines:
  default:
    - parallel:
      - step:
          name: 'Build and Test'
          script:
            - echo "Your build and test goes here..."
      - step:
          name: 'Lint'
          script:
            - echo "Your linting goes here..."
      - step:
          name: 'Security scan'
          script:
            - echo "Your security scan goes here..."

    # The following deployment steps will be executed for each pipeline run. To configure your steps and conditionally deploy see https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/configure-bitbucket-pipelinesyml/
    - step:
        name: 'Deployment to Staging'
        deployment: staging
        script:
          - echo "Your deployment to staging script goes here..."
          - echo $TESTVAR
          - ssh example.net.au ls -l /staging.example.net.au
    - step:
        name: 'Deployment to Production'
        deployment: production
        trigger: 'manual'
        script:
          - echo "Your deployment to production script goes here..."
```

Comment: Interesting question.
Please post the solution when you will find it.

Comment: I will, I posted a similar question to the [Atlassian forum](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/bitbucket-pipeline-connection-timed-out/qaq-p/1702347#M63378) using the actual example from their instructions without any answers also.

Comment: So looking at people trying to connect to bitbucket from their servers, it seems like bitbucket has port 22 blocked, and port 443 instead. so `- ssh example.net.au -p 443 ls -l /staging.example.net.au` but now I'm having ssh errors with at least means I'm making a connection now. Probably just installed my certificates wrong, I'll post as an answer when it's working completely.

Comment: For anyone else coming to this question, it wasn't an issue with the port, the keys weren't setup correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your SSL set-up may be incorrect. Please try the following to ensure both servers trust each other:

==Part 1==

Step 1. SSH into cPanel server (use [PuTTY](https://www.putty.org) or your preferred SSH client), and run the following commands to generate a new key:

```
ssh-keygen
eval $(ssh-agent)
ssh-add
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Step 2. Copy the resulting key from the 'cat' command above, into: Bitbucket -> your repo -> Settings -> Access keys

==Part 2==

Step 3. In Bitbucket, go to your repo -> settings -> SSH keys -> Generate key

Step 4. Back on your cPanel server's SSH connection, copy the key from Step 3 above into the authorized keys file. Save when you are done:

```
nano ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Right click to paste (usually)
CNRL+O to save
CNRL+X to exit

Step 5. In the same Bitbucket screen from Step 3, fetch and add host's fingerprint. You will need to enter the URL or IP address of your cPanel server here. Some cPanels servers use non-default ports. If port 22 is not the correct port, be sure to specify like so:

example.com:2200

(Port 443 is usually reserved for HTTPS and it is unlikely the correct port for an SSH connection. If in doubt, try the default 22 and common alternative 2200 ports first.)

Let me know if you have any questions and I am happy to assist you further.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I had to generate a key set with Putty Key Generator and import it into cPanel (cPanel keygen required a password) so the steps weren't followed exactly but pointed me in the right direction.